# Jupyter Notebook run cell programmatically

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have created ipywidget button for each cell in the output of the first cell. I want to run the cell when i click the button.

display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.execute_cells_below()')). This is working fine. But when it tried to run the specific cell using cell index nothing is happening.

Is there a way to assign fixed index to each cell?

```
# cell 1
from IPython.display import Javascript, display
from ipywidgets import widgets

def run_all(ev):
    display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.execute_cells_below()'))
    #display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.execute_cells(3)'))

button = widgets.Button(description="Create next input")
button.on_click(run_all)
display(button)

#cell 2
print('hi from cell 2')

#cell 3
print('hi from cell 3')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your sintax if wrong. Try this when executing a specific cell:

```
display(Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cell([cell_index])"))
```